# Check if the GET value is null

Tags: php

I have a form that is to be initialized with $_GET of the values posted

```
<?=form('sentopage')?>
<input type='text' name='name' value='<?=$_GET['val']?'/>
<?=form_close()?>
```

This will cause an error if the page is opened with an URL whose 'val' is not there ? I would like to check it first but I don't know how ?

UPDATE

My problem is
I am with an index page, after I fill in a form in the index page then submit, I will be directed to a confirm page, if I then press the button to confirm I will proceed further, if I press the button to re-edit the submitted information, I will be directed back to the index page but some information I entered previously in the text/textarea should not be deleted; that is why I use "index?info=something&inf=somethingelse" etc. But If I leave this in the main page, the first run of the index page will cause an error in the form.

Comment: For the love of science, please sanitize your inputs!

Comment: Short open tags make me cringe. Also, I'm saddened that no one dropped the ternary operation bomb on this question.

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['val'])) { ... } ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this :

`if(empty($_GET['val']))`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

or even

`if(is_null($_GET['val']))`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Answer (score 1):

`isset` is what you're looking for, example:

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_GET['val'])) {

    }
  ?>
```

[And a link to the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['value'])) {
    if($_GET['value'] != NULL) {

     // do something

    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use the empty method as well. Empty not only check if the value of the var you are looking but when you are looking inside an array it also deals with the case where that index isn't set or is set but has a null value.

It's quite powerful as long as you are aware that it does all these things

Comment: If you do an empty check you will also have to do an array_key_exists check as well. Otherwise php will throw notices about invalid array index as 'var' is not guaranteed to be present.